# Doctrine Searchable Behavior vs Zend Lucene in symfony

Tags: symfony1, lucene, doctrine

I need to  search for keywords in 2 table, simple thing

I am undecided about using one or the other? 
any suggestion performance wise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cuhuak mentioned, Lucene is a fulltext search. Since it is written in Java, you additionaly need a Java Server (Tomcat for example). If you don't want an additional server, the [Zend Lucene implementation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html) (as noted in the comments by Matt Gibson) may also be worth looking into. With an additional server and if you only have a small host, this *MAY* not be good performance wise. Also, Lucene needs much more configuration and set-up than the Doctrine solutions.

On the performance side of things: Lucene is built to index millions of words and search within these in milliseconds. With millions of words in your "regular" RDBMS, things will get slow. You could set up a fulltextsearch in the database too, but this again needs setup and knowledge what to do.

So a generall thought: if the site is small (in terms of things to searc), go with the Doctrine approach, if you plan to get serious amounts of data, go with Lucene.

Comment: Note that the [Zend version of Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html) is a full port to PHP5, not just an interface to Java. The current Symfony tutorial sample project, Jobeet, gives an example of plugging this in to Symfony for a PHP-only fulltext search solution.

Comment: @Matt, thanks I wasn't fully aware of that. I updaded my anser to include a reference to Zend. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Lucene has been developed for fulltext search. Do you need this functionality?

If you need only keywords functionality use Searchable
Searchable is easer to use than Lucene.

Also consider to use [sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin)